¿Por qué al usar pandas.read_csv lee toda la información como Unnamed y NaN hasta que lo abro en excel?
Al descargar un reporte csv lo intento importar con:
registros = pandas.read_csv("../../documents/reporte.csv",
                        encoding="latin1",
                        sep=",")

Y la información se carga así:
          Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  ...  Unnamed: 20  Unnamed: 21  Unnamed: 22
0         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN
1         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...          NaN          NaN          NaN

Una vez  que abro el archivo con Excel y le doy en "Guardar" (no "Guardar como") y ejecuto el mismo código la información ya se carga bien. También noté que cambia el peso del archivo.
¿Saben de alguna forma de que se cargue bien la información sin tener que abrir el archivo en Excel primero? y ¿Por qué cambia el peso del archivo?

Sin ver el archivo original (al menos unas filas, pero que permitan reproducir el problema) va a ser complicado dar una respuesta concreta, por favor agrega el CSV o parte de el como texto a la pregunta o al menos un enlace. ¿Por qué no simplemente comparas las diferencias entre el archivo csv antes y despues de guardarlo con excel? Seguramente algo está malformado en el csv original o no coincide con los parámetros que le pasas a read_csv.

Recuerda que los .csv son archivos de texto plano, abrelos con cualquier editor de texto tipo "bloc de notas"  en vez de excel y podrás ver su contenido para comparar (y copiarlo y agregarlo a la pregunta) o puedes usar algún programa que permite ver las diferencias entre documentos.

No pude reproducir Su problema,
pero puedo sugerirle que intente los siguientes pasos:
compruebe la codificación del archivo:
import chardet  # pip install chardet

def detect_encoding(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        raw_data = f.read(10000)
        result = chardet.detect(raw_data)
        encoding = result['encoding']
        confidence = result['confidence']
        return encoding, confidence


file_path = "../../documents/reporte.csv"
encoding, confidence = detect_encoding(file_path)
print(f"Codificación específica: {encoding} (veracidad: {confidence})")

intente sobrescribir el archivo:
import pandas as pd

file_path = "../../documents/reporte.csv"

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    print(*lines, sep='\n')  # compruebe el separador

with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)

registros = pd.read_csv("test.csv",
                        encoding="latin1",
                        sep=",")

cree un marco de datos utilizando el módulo csv:
import csv
import pandas as pd
from rich import inspect  # pip install rich

file_path = "../../documents/reporte.csv"

with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect="excel")
    data = list(reader)
    inspect(data)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
    inspect(df)

salida del último código:
╭─────────────────────── <class 'list'> ───────────────────────╮
│ Built-in mutable sequence.                                   │
│ ╭──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │ [                                                        │ │
│ │ │   ['first', 'second', 'third'],                        │ │
│ │ │   ['1', 'string', '3.14'],                             │ │
│ │ │   ['2', 'charline', '4.75']                            │ │
│ │ ]                                                        │ │
│ ╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
╭────────────────── <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> ──────────────────╮
│ Two-dimensional, size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data.    │
│ ╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │   first    second third                                               │ │
│ │ 0     1    string  3.14                                               │ │
│ │ 1     2  charline  4.75                                               │ │
│ ╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
~                                                                           ~
╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯


Avíseme si algo de esto es útil. ¡Éxito!
